# WCF Deserialization Problems

Tags: web-services, wcf, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am facing de-serialization problems in using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk dll in WCF service.

while generating the client side proxy class, All the derived types of type (DataCollection) is changed to a different namespace and type as mentioed below.

**In DLL**

```
public sealed class AttributeCollection : Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.DataCollection<string,object>{}
```

**In Proxy Using (SvcUtil)**

```
public class AttributeCollection : System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, object>> {
}
```

Regards,

Ranjith

Comment: Please explain how you are creating proxy class, I have generated code many times using svcutil but never came across this issue.

Comment: @Scorpion, Using the below command line  'svcutil.exe /r:Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll https://somedomain.com/service.svc'